# Creating a second VAO and drawing two shapes in OpenGL 4

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader, vao

I am trying to solve the experiments in the book Anton's OpenGL 4 Tutorials. In the first chapter's experiments it ask to create a second VAO to draw 2 shapes instead of one but I have no clue how to do this, how can a second be displayed simultaneously?

```
    #include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
    if (!glfwInit ()) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return 1;
    } 
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit ();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

    GLfloat points[] = {
    0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
    0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
    };

    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 18 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray (vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    //second vao
    GLuint vao_two = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_two);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_two);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    const char* vertex_shader =
    "#version 400\n"
    "in vec3 vp;"
    "in vec3 vp2;"
    "void main() {"
    " gl_Position = vec4(vp.x, vp.y + 0.2, vp.z, 1.0);"
    " gl_Position2 = vec4(vp2.x, vp2.y - 0.9, vp2.z, 1.0);"
    "}";

    const char* fragment_shader =
    "#version 400\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;"
    "void main () {"
    "  frag_colour = vec4 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (vs);

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fs);

    GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
    glLinkProgram(shader_programme);

    glClearColor(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose (window)) {
        // wipe the drawing surface clear
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram (shader_programme);
        glBindVertexArray (vao);
        // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
        glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindVertexArray (vao_two);
        glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        // update other events like input handling 
        glfwPollEvents ();
        // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
    }
    // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you are using "in vec3 vp2;" and  " gl_Position2 = vec4(vp2.x, vp2.y - 0.9, vp2.z, 1.0);" in your shader program? They are expendable

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are drawing two different shapes, however, because you use the same vertex buffer object in both vertex attribute objects (vao and vao_two) they have the same coordinates and they overlap. 
Try to make 2 GLfloat arrays of points with different coordinates and attribute each one to a different vertex buffer object and then each vertex buffer object to a different vertex attribute object, then your shapes will be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

First bind the buffers and then draw them all:

```
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Alternatively you can draw first the first shape and then the second:

```
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(vao2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
```